# Matplotlib: add trends (lines between markers) on a graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two dataframe: `df, df_trend, df_return`, they all have the same timeframe: `'2019-01-01 01:00:00.000Z' AND '2019-01-15 23:59:59.999Z'`

What I did right now is to plot the prices of df: `df.plot(y='price', x='time')`

What I tried to do is to add the trends of df_trend and df_return by adding markers on the graph:

```
`plt.scatter(df_trend[df_trend.event == 'crossing up'].time.tolist(),
    df_trend[df_trend.event == 'crossing up'].price.tolist(),    
            marker='v')

plt.scatter(df_trend[df_trend.event == 'crossing down'].time.tolist(),
    df_trend[df_trend.event == 'crossing down'].price.tolist(),    
            marker='1')

plt.scatter(df_return[df_return.return12 > 0].time.tolist(),
    df_return[df_return.return12 > 0].price.tolist(),    
            marker='2')

plt.scatter(df_return[df_return.return12 < 0].time.tolist(),
    df_return[df_return.return12 < 0].price.tolist(),    
            marker='3')`
```

This add markers for an uptrend and downtrend (`crossing up` / `crossing down`) in df_trend, and do the same with df_return (`return12 > 0`, `return12 < 0`). What I would like to do is to instead of putting markers, connect every point by a line (with colors if possible). Any idea on how to proceed? thanks!